# How to change the product short description for each product with PHP?

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, tags

Do you have any idea how to change the short description?

What is the meta key that is used in order to assign a specific value to the short description?

if I want to change the price I use:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', $ItemPrice);
```

What meta tag should I use for the short description?

Comment: can you be specific about `short description` ? is it the excerpt ?

Comment: Yes I have seen it come across as excerpt. It is this field in the screenshot. http://prntscr.com/ha7l2o

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the excerpt (also called short description) and it's not stored as a meta value. It's stored with the post in the `post_excerpt` column.

So you can try something like this :

```
// Update product with id = 44
  $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => 44,
      'post_excerpt'   => 'New text',
  );

// Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post( $my_post );
```